# $select=body not working while creating Subscription | Microsoft Graph API

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-mail

Description
I'm encountering an issue while attempting to create a subscription to receive change notifications, including resource data, in the Microsoft Graph API. Here's the payload I'm using:

```
{
"changeType": "created",
"notificationUrl": "\<URL\>",
"resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages?$select=body",
"expirationDateTime": "2024-02-26T21:00:00.000Z",
"latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2",
"includeResourceData": "true",
"encryptionCertificate": "\<SOME VALUE\>",
"encryptionCertificateId": "\<SOME VALUE\>"
}
```

However, upon sending a POST request with this payload, I'm encountering the following error message:

`$top`, `$skip`, `$orderby`, `$select=body,uniqueBody` and $expand other than singleValueExtendedProperties,multiValueExtendedProperties are not supported in subscription resource Url.
This error suggests that including `$select=body` in the resource URL is not permitted. If I exclude `$select=body`, I encounter a different error:

"select clause should be present in query string to support rich notifications"
This indicates that a select clause is required in the query string to support rich notifications.

Additionally, when I attempted to use `$select=bodyPreview`, I only received a truncated version of the body limited to 255 characters.

My objective is to receive change notifications including the entire body of the resource. I'm seeking guidance on how to achieve this.